# How to create scheduled task with custom event triggers in C#?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I want to create a login task when connecting to certain WIFI in my program.
I used the following code:

```
using TaskScheduler;


   public static _TASK_STATE CreateLoginTaskScheduler( string taskName, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            //实例化任务对象
            TaskSchedulerClass scheduler = new TaskSchedulerClass();
            scheduler.Connect(null, null, null, null);
            ITaskFolder folder = scheduler.GetFolder("\\");
            //设置常规属性
            ITaskDefinition task = scheduler.NewTask(0);
            task.RegistrationInfo.Author = Environment.UserName;
            task.RegistrationInfo.Description = "描述信息";//description
            task.Principal.RunLevel = _TASK_RUNLEVEL.TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST; 
                                                                            
            ILogonTrigger tt = (ILogonTrigger)task.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON); 
            tt.UserId = Environment.MachineName + "\\" + Environment.UserName; 
            IEventTrigger con1 = (IEventTrigger)task.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_EVENT);//how can I create custom event triggers with XML?


            IExecAction action = (IExecAction)task.Actions.Create(_TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC);
            action.Path = path;
            action.Arguments = "login";
            task.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT0S";
            task.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;
            task.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
            task.Settings.WakeToRun = true;

            
            
            IRegisteredTask regTask = folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
            taskName,
            task,
            (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_CREATE, 
            null, //user
            null, // password
            _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, //Principal.LogonType
            "");

            IRunningTask runTask = regTask.Run(null);
            return runTask.State;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

The problem occurs when I want to set the event trigger by xml below

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig'] and (EventID=8001)]][EventData[Data[@Name='SSID']='WIFINAME']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

how can I do this?

I don't know how to use value queries or something else to create the trigger

Comment: side note: `catch (Exception ex)  { throw ex; }` <- Don't do this. You will lose all tracing information. Just use `throw` without `ex` to rethrow the same exception. But if you just catch and rethrow without doing anything else, the whole try-catch is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: "The problem occurs" what problem?

Comment: I don't know how to define the event trigger's settings XD

Comment: I got it 'IEventTrigger con1 = (IEventTrigger)task.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_EVENT);
                con1.Subscription = "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational'><Select Path='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational'>*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig'] and (EventID=8001)]][EventData[Data[@Name='SSID']='WIFINAME']]</Select></Query></QueryList>";'             just set the subscription value as the xml goes :D